# CKEditor HTML Autocorrection Issue

Tags: ckeditor

I have few lines of HTML in my database. I want to edit the content in CKEditor. But when I open that in editor the HTML gets break down. The HTML gets rearranged.

Below is the HTML which is in database:

```
<span class="sec_title">
       <h1><span>Web</span> Engineering</h1>
        <hr>
</span>
```

And when I open it in CKEditor the HTML looks likes below:

```
<h1><span class="sec_title"><span>Web</span> Engineering</span></h1>

<hr />
```

**Some one please help me. I tried `config.allowedContent = true;` but it is also not stopping the CKEditor to do the modifications.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CKEditor works with a valid HTML only and `<h1>` is not a valid content of `<span>`. Quoting [CKEditor basic concepts](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_basics):

> CKEditor is not a tool that will let you input invalid HTML code. CKEditor abides by W3C standards so it will modify code if it is invalid.